# What did it take for Solana's first block to be created?

Tags: history

The [Solana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solana_(blockchain_platform)) blockchain platform was proposed in a [2017 whitepaper](https://docs.solana.com/history).

What happened between then and  [Block 0](https://explorer.solana.com/block/0)'s creation on March 16, 2020 at 14:29:00 UTC?

Comment: If you look at the commits on Github you can see all the work that went into bringing it to life.  Work started right after the whitepaper but It takes a while to get from concept to a functioning product.  Then of course there's running it in testnet and hashing out the issues.

Comment: @Mocolicious Since I'm a beginner (I made note of this in the commitment phase in Area51), I didn't even know to check a GitHub repo, or even which GitHub repo to check! I think you've provided the beginning of what would be an excellent answer to this question, but it's too bad that it got closed a bit earlier. Hopefully we get 3 more re-open votes :)

Comment: thanks.  Its still unclear to me why this would get closed.  here's a link to the earliest commits and you can see for yourself if you click through each one, very interesting. https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/commits/master?after=06ae906e9000608423484e3e91363560c50aa615+19574&branch=master&qualified_name=refs%2Fheads%2Fmaster

Comment: @Mocolicious The first commit seems to have been 3 months after the whitepaper!

Comment: yes and they were calling it "Loomination" at the time